# update particular object of features array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I am struggling to update the particular object from features array and returning the whole object with the updated one. I could update the particular object but could not return the same whole object with the updated one. I am doing this using immutablejs. Here is my code

```
    case EDIT_FEATURE_SUCCESS: {
  return state
    .set('requesting', false)
    .set('response', action.response.data.message)
    .update('features', features =>
      state.get('features').map(feat => {
        return {
          ...feat,
          features: features.map(feature => {
            if (feature._id === action.response.data.featureObj._id) {
              return action.response.data.featureObj;
            } else return feature;
          })
        };
      })
    );
}
```

I need the following object

[image]

with the updated one but I am getting something like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immutablejs seems complex when its about updating the nested object. You can try this one. Let me know if it works or not. In my view, it should work

```
case EDIT_FEATURE_SUCCESS: {
  return state
    .set('requesting', false)
    .set('response', action.response.data.message)
    .update('features', features =>
      features.map(feat => {
        return {
          ...feat,
          features: feat.features.map(feature => {
            if (feature._id === action.response.data.featureObj._id) {
              return action.response.data.featureObj;
            } else return feature;
          })
        };
      })
    );
}
```

In the code, I have changed `state.get('features')` to `features` which is just shortening the line of code. The problem is you are doing `features.map` instead it should be `feat.features` because feat will have features array that you are exactly updating.

Comment: Yeah I consoled log to see the feat.features which has array of object which I am updating. Its very very helpful as nested update is most likely to occur in probably every project. Thanks for your help.